# Couchdb view Queries

Tags: view, couchdb

Could you please help me in creating a view. Below is the requirement

```
select * from personaccount where name="srini" and user="pup" order by lastloggedin
```

I have to send name and user as input to the view and the data should be sorted by lastloggedin.

Below is the view I have created but it is not working

```
{
    "language": "javascript",
    "views": {
        "sortdatetimefunc": {
            "map": "function(doc) {
                emit({
                    lastloggedin: doc.lastloggedin,
                    name:         doc.name,
                    user:         doc.user
                },doc);
            }"
        }
    }
}
```

And this the curl command iam using:

```
http://uta:password@localhost:5984/personaccount/_design/checkdatesorting/_view/sortdatetimefunc?key={\"name:srini\",\"user:pup\"}
```

My Questions are

As sorting will be done on key and I want it on lastloggedin so I have given that also in emit function.

But iam passing name and user only as parameters. Do we need to pass all the parameters which we give it in key?

---

First of all I want to convey to you for the reply, I have done the same and iam getting  errors. Please help

Could you please try this on your PC, iam posting all the commands :

```
curl -X PUT http://uta:password@localhost:5984/person-data

curl -X PUT http://uta:password@localhost:5984/person-data/srini -d '{"Name":"SRINI", "Idnum":"383896", "Format":"NTSC", "Studio":"Disney", "Year":"2009", "Rating":"PG", "lastTimeOfCall": "2012-02-08T19:44:37+0100"}'

curl -X PUT http://uta:password@localhost:5984/person-data/raju -d '{"Name":"RAJU", "Idnum":"456787", "Format":"FAT", "Studio":"VFX", "Year":"2010", "Rating":"PG", "lastTimeOfCall": "2012-02-08T19:50:37+0100"}'

curl -X PUT http://uta:password@localhost:5984/person-data/vihar -d '{"Name":"BALA", "Idnum":"567876", "Format":"FAT32", "Studio":"YELL", "Year":"2011", "Rating":"PG", "lastTimeOfCall": "2012-02-08T19:55:37+0100"}'
```

Here's the view as you said I created :

```
{
   "_id": "_design/persondestwo",
   "_rev": "1-0d3b4857b8e6c9e47cc9af771c433571",
   "language": "javascript",
   "views": {
       "personviewtwo": {
           "map": "function (doc) {\u000a    emit([ doc.Name, doc.Idnum, doc.lastTimeOfCall ], null);\u000a}"
       }
   }
}


I have fired this command from curl command :

curl -X GET http://uta:password@localhost:5984/person-data/_design/persondestwo/_view/personviewtwo?startkey=["SRINI","383896"]&endkey=["SRINI","383896",{}]descending=true&include_docs=true
```

I got this error :

```
[4] 3000
curl: (3) [globbing] error: bad range specification after pos 99
[5] 1776
[6] 2736
[3]   Done                    descending=true
[4]   Done(3)                 curl -X GET http://uta:password@localhost:5984/person-data/_design/persondestwo/_view/personviewtwo?startkey=["SRINI","383896"]
[5]   Done                    endkey=["SRINI","383896"]
```

I am not knowing what this error is.

I have also tried passing the parameters the below way and it is not helping

```
curl -X GET http://uta:password@localhost:5984/person-data/_design/persondestwo/_view/personviewtwo?key={\"Name\":\"SRINI\",\"Idnum\": \"383896\"}&descending=true
```

But I get different errors on escape sequences

Overall I just want this query to be satisfied through the view :

```
select * from person-data where Name="SRINI" and Idnum="383896" orderby lastTimeOfCall
```

My concern is how to pass the multiple parameters from curl command as I get lot of errors if I do the above way.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to use an array as your key. I would use:

```
function (doc) {
    emit([ doc.name, doc.user, doc.lastLoggedIn ], null);
}
```

This basically outputs all the documents in order by name, then user, then lastLoggedIn. You can use the following URL to query.

```
/_design/checkdatesorting/_view/sortdatetimefunc?startkey=["srini","pup"]&endkey=["srini","pup",{}]&include_docs=true
```

Second, notice I did not output `doc` as the value of your query. It takes up much more disk space, especially if your documents are fairly large. Just use `include_docs=true`.

Lastly, refer to the CouchDB [Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation), it's pretty helpful.

Comment: Hi Dominic, First of all i want to convey thanks to you for the reply, I have done the same and i get errors

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this question. The errors you are getting are caused by not escaping this command:

```
curl -X GET http://uta:password@localhost:5984/person-data/_design/persondestwo/_view/personviewtwo?startkey=["SRINI","383896"]&endkey=["SRINI","383896",{}]descending=true&include_docs=true
```

The & character has a special meaning on the command-line and should be escaped when part of an actual parameter. 
So you should put quotes around the big URL, and escape the quotes inside it:

```
curl -X GET "http://uta:password@localhost:5984/person-data/_design/persondestwo/_view/personviewtwo?startkey=[\"SRINI\",\"383896\"]&endkey=[\"SRINI\",\"383896\",{}]descending=true&include_docs=true"
```